# PDF слайдер для сайта

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли какая-нибудь HTML/JS библиотека-слайдер для файлов в формате .pdf с кнопками переключения next/prev?
В идеале хотелось бы чтобы библиотека имела простую установку и настройку.

Comment: вы хотите листать страницы пдф, или переключать отдельные пдф файлы?

Answer (score 0):

Можно превратить .pdf в .jpg через библиотеки и через URL уже грузить на Ваш сайт, но чистый .pdf наврядли. По крайней мере, подобного я еще не видал.
Есть сайтик [FlowPaper](https://flowpaper.com/#), может такой способ подойдет, однако, там уже за денюшку.